# How to aggregate petition signers

Tags: forms, petition

WP 6 Civi 5.51

We'd like to  "Find contacts who have signed x number of petitions"
It seems to me that built in petitions, activities, custom field/profiles cannot provide this.

Contributions is a possibility with financial type = petition signature as there are a range of aggregate searches. However contribution pages/forms don't lend themselves to this because of $amounts etc, unless I am missing something?

The new form builder might solve the $label issue but doesn't seem to offer contribution fields.

Caldera defunct, Ninja no contribs, Gravity no contribs.

Anything I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SearchKit, you can search by Contact with required Activity or Contribution, group by Contact ID and then use the Count field transformation on the Activity or Contribution ID, then add Having Count > N.